# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: zend-framework

I am getting this error whenever I run the application. I followed the steps given in this url:http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/zend-framework-from-scratch-models-and-integrating-doctrine-orm--net-23654 .

It is a very helpful one. But I don't know where I made a mistake. I tried the answers given before for many other questions posted in the same manner.

I tried altering the `application.ini file` too. But it isn't working. Please guide me as soon as possible.

My application.ini looks like this:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH"/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers" 
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

[staging : production]
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.dbname = "thenextsocial"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "[your local database username]"
resources.db.params.password = "[your local database password]"

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Comment: Please include the minimum amount of code required to duplicate this issue.

Comment: Sorry Sir. I should have included the code before. But I don't know which code to include. The error actually shows up in application.ini file. I have included that. I am a beginner in Zend. please excuse me for my mistakes and silly questions. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, the best I can do is explain what the error means.

Your code has encountered a `=` when it was expecting something else. It could be that you are trying to initialise a variable and included a semi-colon accidentally:

```
$var; = "value";
```

The error message should also include the class and line number the error has occurred on. Look at that line and the line immediately before - you may find there is an unexpected character in your code.

As the exception is of type `Zend_Config_Exception` I suspect this is something to do with your `application.ini` file. Make sure there are no new-lines or other characters in each line.

Comment: My application.ini file looks like this:

Comment: [production]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0 

phpSettings.display_errors = 0

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH"/../library"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"

bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

appnamespace = "Application"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0 
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

Comment: [staging : production]

resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"

resources.db.params.dbname = "thenextsocial"

resources.db.params.host = "localhost"

resources.db.params.username = "[your local database username]"
resources.db.params.password = "[your local database password]"

[testing : production]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1

phpSettings.display_errors = 1 


[development : production]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1

phpSettings.display_errors = 1

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

Answer (score 0):

In Config.ini

change `Password = yourpassword`

To:   `Password = 'yourpassword'`